# How to write a program to print the hollow diamond pattern similar to the pattern shown?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example: If the given number is 5, the pattern should contain 9 rows and 9 columns as shown below.

```
    A
   B B
  C   C
 D     D
E       E
 D     D
  C   C
   B B
    A
```

If the given number is 3, the pattern should contain 5 rows and 5 columns as shown below.

```
   A
  B B
 C   C
  B B
   A
```

Comment: Which part do you have difficulties with ?

Comment: I rolled back the [previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66459019/3). If you have a completely new question, then [ask](/ask) a new question. Please don't edit questions and replace them with completely new ones.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things we need to consider. Lets say the number given was 30, this means the alphabets should round around and repeat. When we have this situation, we need a modulus which is `%` in python.

The other thing is how do we centre the string? In python, there's a string method called `center` which takes an integer specifying the length of the centered string and also an optional argument which is set to space which is what we need.

Looking at the diamonds you have in the question, we can observe a pattern. The max length is the nth odd number which can be found with this formula: Nth odd number = `N*2-1`

This is the same for the number of spaces between the 2 characters in each row.

How do we get the characters? We can do this easily with the `chr` function which converts ascii character values to an actual character. Looking at the ascii table, capital alphabets start with code 65. Using this we can create this code for handling the alphabets. `chr(n%26+65)`

So, here's the code:

```py
row = int(input(': '))

n = row*2-1  # The length to center the string with.

# Upper part of diamond
for i in range(row):
    if i == 0:  # if it is the first iteration, then print out 1 character only centered
        print('A'.center(n))
        continue  # skip this iteration. essentially skipping the latter code.
    character = chr(i%26+65)  # the character to be used for the sides.
    print(f"{character}{' '*(2*i-1)}{character}".center(n))  # printing the line itself. if you didn't know, you can multiply strings with integers to result in that character/string being repeated integer times.

# Lower part of the diamond. Same thing as above, but mirrored.
for i in range(0, row-1)[::-1]:
    if i == 0:
        print('A'.center(n))
        continue
    character = chr(i%26+65)
    print(f"{character}{' '*(2*i-1)}{character}".center(n))
```

That's all! Happy coding!

Comment: If you're confused with the ascii part, [here's a website with a table containing all the ascii characters](https://asciitable.com) including the extended ones as well. And a [video to explain what it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zB85kTs-sEw&ab_channel=BitMerge).

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that. At least your answer explains how it works, but the question itself is off-topic and [should not be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/354577).

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't know that. Thanks for informing! I'll follow them next time I do answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Vertically, you want to go through letters in order and then in reversed order (not repeating the last one).

with `L = "ABCDE"`,  this corresponds to `L+L[-2::-1]` = "ABCDEDCBA"

Horizontally, you are doing this in reverse `L[::-1]+L[1:]]` = "EDCBABCDE".

By intersecting the horizontal and vertical letters in a list comprehension, you get a list of lists containing the diamond pattern which you can then print line by line (with no separation between characters of the nested lists)

```
L = "ABCDE"

lines  = [[(' ',c)[c==s] for s in L[::-1]+L[1:]] for c in L+L[-2::-1]]
for line in lines:
    print(*line,sep="")


    A    
   B B   
  C   C  
 D     D 
E       E
 D     D 
  C   C  
   B B   
    A
```

- `for c in L+L[-2::-1]` produces one row per character vertically based on the vertical order of characters (each character placed in `c`)
- `for s in L[::-1]+L[1:]` runs through the horizontal pattern to build each line (nested list)
- `(' ',c)[c==s]` selects spaces for every character in the horizontal pattern that doesn't match the line's letter.
- this forms a list of lists in the `lines` variable
- `for line in lines` goes through these lines for printing
- `print(*line,sep="")` prints the current line without separators between characters

If you want it to print faster, you can join the letters in the nested lists to from strings that you can print directly:

```
print(*map("".join,lines),sep="\n")
```

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that. At least your answer explains how it works, but the question itself is off-topic and [should not be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/354577).